# How to print MaxPath of graph using dfs O(n)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, vector, depth-first-search

We want to find the farthest vertex to the i-th vertex,

farthest vertex to the current vertex of graph, gives the maximum Path to us.

Please help me to get this right:

```
vector<int> v[100];
bool mark[100];
int v1;

inline int max_path(int k)
{
    int result = -1;
    mark[k] = true;
    for(int i=0; i<v[k].size(); i++)
        if(!mark[v[k][i]])
        {
            int x = max_path(v[k][i]);
            if(x > result)
            {
                result = x;
                v1 = v[k][i];
            }
        }
    return result+1;
}
```

v1 must be the farthest vertex to the current vertex (k), and  result must be the length of the path.

Comment: "What is wrong with this code" is not an appropriate question for StackOverflow.

Comment: The simplest way would be to find shortest path to evety node in the graph.

Comment: What does "farthest vertex" and "maximum Path" means to you? What if there is more than one path to every other vertex, which path do you want, the longest or the shortest?

Comment: longest path if starts with a, and then between end of that and now 2nd is the max path of graph

Comment: Do you mean this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're looking for? Do you want the node at the greatest distance from a start node `a`, or do you want the longest path in the graph that starts at `a`?

Comment: DFS would give you the max path. do you want yo know how to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `int result[n]` and then print the max var of that...